Why I couldn't pass a lambda expression which captured a unique_ptr to std::packaged_task?
I tried to pass a lambda expr like this:
  auto uptr1 = std::make_unique<int>(1);
  std::packaged_task<void()> task([uptr = std::move(uptr1)]() { std::cout << *uptr << std::endl; });

to std::packaged_task.
But a compilation error occurs:
compilation error screen shot
Why is the copy constructor called instead of the move constructor?Do I have to pass std::packaged_task a callable object that supports copying?
I tried to change like this:
  auto uptr1 = std::make_unique<int>(1);
  std::packaged_task<void()> task(std::move(
      [uptr = std::move(uptr1)]() { std::cout << *uptr << std::endl; }));

But it still falis to compile.....

std::packaged_task seems to require copiable task...

Please do not upload images of error messages.

Good news: MS accepts it's a bug! Bad news: it's an ABI break so no release yet https://developercommunity.visualstudio.com/t/unable-to-move-stdpackaged-task-into-any-stl-conta/108672

https://godbolt.org/z/34YPcr4co

Offtopic: this first move in your example is obsolete, since this lambda is already the r-value.
